# How do I hide the Android Keyboard when using React-Native-Gifted-Chat?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo, react-native-gifted-chat

I am using React-Native-Gifted-Chat in my RN/Expo app. When a user goes to type a message, the message box should move up with the keyboard . This is the behavior I get on iOS, but with Android, it covers up the box.

I've tried enclosing a "KeyboardAvoidingView" around the "GiftedChat" prop, but it pushes the message box outside the screen.

I've also tried what is seen below, and while the keyboard doesn't go away, it still covers the message box when typing.

Below is my code:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView>
    <SafeAreaView style = { styles.header }>
      <GiftedChat
        messages={}
        showAvatarForEveryMessage={true}
        onSend={messages => onSend(messages)}
        user={{
          _id:1,
        }}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>  
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Comment: This should help you: https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat/issues/435

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the solution below worked for me, but it might have only worked because this screen is simply a "Chat Screen" meaning:

Someone goes to this screen for the purpose of sending and receiving messages, nothing else.

To solve this, I eliminated all of the "Views" and it gave me the behavior I wanted.

Below is the updated code:

```
return(
    <GiftedChat
        messages={}
        showAvatarForEveryMessage={true}
        onSend={messages => onSend(messages)}
        user={{
          _id:1,
        }}
    />
)
```

Answer (score 0):

for Hiding the keyboard while scrolling chat  or back tap just add this

```
return(
      <GiftedChat
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'never'}
       />
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed mine. I had to use an hardcoded value of 80. This is the default height of stack screens header on android.

```
// Fixes Android keyboard covering input (default header height: 80)
  {Platform.OS === "android" && (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView keyboardVerticalOffset={80} behavior='padding' />
  )}
```

So to use this code, add `<GiftedChat />` and `<KeyboardAvoidingView />` in a `SafeAreaView`:

```
return (
<SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <GiftedChat />
  
  {Platform.OS === "android" && (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView keyboardVerticalOffset={80} behavior='padding' />
  )}
</SafeAreaView>
);
```

You can check out this if you wanna [get the header height dynamically](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/elements/#useheaderheight)